# Use prototypal inheritance vs delegation pattern

Tags: javascript

I have two code example which do same thing. 
But this is interesting me which is best in this use case. I know **prototypal inheritance** actually **behavior delegation pattern**. But you can see in my first example I use to prototype for store helper methods second one when I need helpers I create new instance helper class and use this instance. After used this instance Garbage Collected.

This is interesting for me which is best? 
When I create new instance function call time is this noticeable performance problem?

```
class UserHelper {
    checkFileSize() {

    }

    fileUpload() {

    }

}

class User extends UserHelper {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        super()
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    changeUserAvatar() {
        this.checkFileSize();
        this.fileUpload();
    }
}

const murad = new User();
```

VS

```
class UserHelper {

    checkFileSize() {

    }

    fileUpload() {

    }

}

class User {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    changeUserAvatar() {
        const helper = new UserHelper();
        helper.checkFileSize();
        helper.fileUpload();
    }
}

const murad = new User();
```

Comment: As they are helpers, you can just make the helpers method static so that you don't need to create a new instance while using them. If you still want to make a new instance, consider making a singleton of helpers

Comment: Not sure how your second snippet would work without context or args, but if you plan to send `this` as arg, its bad convention. Instead, set those functions to prototype

Comment: Prototypal inheritance is no more a delegation pattern than it would be with C++. Delegation pattern is delegation pattern; it is closely related to composition, not inheritance in general. There is a single prototype where everything is delegated, and you'd be hard pressed to produce working design where you'd have to carefully design your prototype chain so that everything is properly delegated. Much easier to have references to objects and delegate to them from your object. You are abusing prototype-based inheritance, with the worst that can happen is your *intent* is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious advantages of using *helpers* is that you can reuse it multiple times in multiples classes and methods without being limited by inheritance issues. For the same reason it will help to keep you codebase on [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles.